# .htaccess 301 from w/o subdirectory to subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Maybe this is a simple thing but I really don't get it.

I have some URLs with this structure
`https://www.somedomain.com/this-is-a-slug-for-page-1/123456789/`

I want to to a 301 for every URL with this pattern to
`https://www.somedomain.com/product/this-is-a-slug-for-page-1/123456789/`

I thought, I could make it like this but I does not work correctly:
`RewriteRule ^(.+)/[0-9]+?$ $1/product$2 [R=301,L]`

Hope you can help me solving this issue with a little bit of explanation for a better understanding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is not capturing 2 groups. You can use this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!product/).+/\d+/?$ /product/$0 [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

`(?!product/)` is a negative lookhead that will skip this rule if URI is already starting with `/product/`